# Getting several answers from function

Tags: python, function

Well, I'm not sure it's possible to do what I want to do. And I want to get several answers instead of just one when I call the function.

Right now I have two functions: `find_files` and `create_tables`. The first one (`find_files`) searches for the given phrase in excel file and returns it (the file, not the phrase). The second one (`create_tables`) - sends the word combination to be found to the first one:

```
def find_files(send):
    os.chdir('C:/data/Tables v4.0/directory_for_excel')
    xlsx_s = os.listdir()
    for xlsx in xlsx_s:
        if xlsx.endswith('.xlsx'):
            wbSearch = load_workbook(xlsx)
            wsSearch = wbSearch.active
            value = wsSearch.cell(row=9, column=1).value
            if value == send:
                return xlsx
    os.chdir('../')


def create_tables():
    specialities = open('specialities.txt', 'r')
    while True:
        speciality = specialities.readline().rstrip()
        get_file = find_files(send=speciality)
        print(get_file)
        if not speciality:
            break
```

And everything would be fine, except that I need to get all the files that contain the word combination I'm looking for, not just the first.

However, for perfectly logical reasons, after the file was found, `return xlsx` comes into play, interrupting the loop.

So, how do I get all the files that contain the expression I'm looking for, not just one?

Is there some way to get them into memory and send them all together? Or is my approach to the question fundamentally wrong?

Comment: A typical way is to build a list, e.g. `result = []`, and then `result.append(xlsx)` to add things to it. At the end of the function, `return result`

Comment: Or use `yield` instead of `return`.  In either case, the calling code will have to be modified to iterate over the return value, rather than using it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy). Finally code looks like:

```
def find_files(send):
    os.chdir('C:/data/Tables v4.0/directory_for_excel')
    xlsx_s = os.listdir()
    result = []
    for xlsx in xlsx_s:
        if xlsx.endswith('.xlsx'):
            wbSearch = load_workbook(xlsx)
            wsSearch = wbSearch.active
            value = wsSearch.cell(row=9, column=1).value
            if value == send:
                result.append(xlsx)
    return result


def create_tables():
    specialities = open('specialities.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    while True:
        speciality = specialities.readline().rstrip()
        if not speciality:
            break
        result = find_files(send=speciality)
        print(result)
```

It returns exactly what I needed.